# Getting error in run sonarqube using Gradle on Java project

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I'm using Gradle 8.5 when I run the following the Gradle sonarqube command then I below error. I suspect something is wrong in my configuration of sonarqube in `build.gradle` file

```
$ ./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.projectKey=${VAR_SONAR_PROJECT_NAME} -Dsonar.projectName=${VAR_SONAR_PROJECT_NAME} -Dsonar.host.url="${VAR_SONAR_URL}" -Dsonar.login=${VAR_SONAR_TOKEN} -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

**Error:-**

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
............10%.............20%............30%.............40%........
.....50%............60%.............70%.............80%............90%.............100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.5!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for running on Java 21
 - Faster first use with Kotlin DSL
 - Improved error and warning messages
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :buildSrc:extractPluginRequests
> Task :buildSrc:generatePluginAdapters
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovyPlugins
> Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors
> Task :buildSrc:processResources
> Task :buildSrc:classes
> Task :buildSrc:jar
> Task :list:compileJava
> Task :utilities:compileJava
> Task :app:compileJava
> Task :app:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:classes
> Task :app:compileTestJava
> Task :app:sonarqube
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
'java.io.File org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.JUnitXmlReport.getDestination()'
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 1m 31s
11 actionable tasks: 11 executed
```

**build.gradle:-**

```
plugins {
    id 'demo.app.java-application-conventions'
    id 'war'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
    id 'jacoco'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text'
    implementation project(':utilities')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'demo.app.app.App'
}


sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.module", "$project.name"
        property "sonar.sources", "app/src/main"
        property "sonar.tests", "app/src/test"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/classes"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle 8.1.1 - What went wrong: 'java.io.File org.gradle.api.reporting.ConfigurableReport.getDestination()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75457142/gradle-8-1-1-what-went-wrong-java-io-file-org-gradle-api-reporting-configura)